# PowerShell: Conditional CSV cell value

Tags: powershell, csv

In table.csv there are already columns named Enrolled and Status. There are other columns, but they are not relevant.

| Enrolled | Status |
| --- | --- |
| 7/28/2021 13:37 | Unknown |
| 7/21/2021 13:37 | Unknown |
| 7/14/2021 13:37 | Unknown |

If Enrolled date is less than 1 week ago from today, the Status cell is changed to PAST DUE

If Enrolled date is greater than 1 week ago from today it becomes DISABLE

If Enrolled date is greater than 2 weeks ago from today it becomes DISABLED STILL PAST DUE

The end result should change table.csv to look like this:

| Enrolled | Status |
| --- | --- |
| 7/28/2021 13:37 | PAST DUE |
| 7/21/2021 13:37 | DISABLE |
| 7/14/2021 13:37 | DISABLED STILL PAST DUE |

```
$csv = Import-Csv file.csv
$pastdue = (Get-Date).AddDays(-7)
foreach($i in $csv.Enrolled){
    if ($i -lt $pastdue){
        ???
    }
}
```

I'm thinking the switch function may be useful, but not sure how to implement it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, using a [`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Switch) statement is an option.

You can combine it with [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) and a [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Calculated_Properties):

```sh
$oneWeekAgo = (Get-Date).Date.AddDays(-7)
$twoWeeksAgo = (Get-Date).Date.AddDays(-14)

$csv | Select-Object Enrolled, @{ 
         Name = 'Status'
         Expression = {
          switch ([datetime] $_.Enrolled) {
            { $_ -lt $twoWeeksAgo } { 'DISABLED STILL PAST DUE'; break }
            { $_ -lt $oneWeekAgo }  { 'DISABLE'; break }
            default                 { 'PAST DUE' }
          } 
         }
       }
```

The above outputs the resulting objects to the display, showing (just) the `Enrolled` and `Status` columns in tabular form, as in your question.

---

**In order to update the original CSV file while only updating the `Status` column and leaving all others intact**, use the following:

- To be safe, back up `file.csv` first.
- Note the enclosure of the [`Import-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv) call in `(...`), which ensures that it is read in full, up front, which enables updating the same file in the same pipeline; if the file is too large to fit into memory, remove the `(...)`, output to a temporary file, then replace the original file with the temporary one.
- You may have to add an `-Encoding` argument to the [`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv) call, because the latter's *default* encoding is otherwise applied, which is ASCII(!) in Windows PowerShell, and, more sensibly, BOM-less UTF-8 in PowerShell (Core) 7+.

```sh
$oneWeekAgo = (Get-Date).Date.AddDays(-7)
$twoWeeksAgo = (Get-Date).Date.AddDays(-14)

(Import-Csv file.csv) | ForEach-Object {

  # Update the .Status property.
  $_.Status = switch ([datetime] $_.Enrolled) {
            { $_ -lt $twoWeeksAgo } { 'DISABLED STILL PAST DUE'; break }
            { $_ -lt $oneWeekAgo }  { 'DISABLE'; break }
            default                 { 'PAST DUE' }
          } 

  # Output the modified object.
  $_

} | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation file.csv
```